# Google Cloud Storage fonts CORS issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, cors, google-cloud-storage

Static files in my app are uploaded to GCS and are set to public links.
when a static resource is requested (in this case a font) it hits a url like `https://example.com/static/fonts/font.woff`
the server then redirects the request to the apropriate GCS url to be served.

the problem here is that with chrome i get this CORS issue:

```
xxxxxxxxe3b8ccc0e3:1 Font from origin 'https://storage.googleapis.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

the CORS defaults on the bucket and all subfolders is set like so:

```
[{"origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"], "method": ["GET"], "maxAgeSeconds": 3600}]
```

the question is where is this credentials flag set? 
i do redirect to the public link so its not an ajax request, the link is in the font-face declaration of the css file.

also it is not an option to set the origin to a specific domain or list of domains because my app is multitenant and there are multiple different domains accessing the same file.

this seems to work correctly when the request comes from `http` but gives this error when on `https`
also this works as expected in safari but does not with chrome.

Comment: How are you loading the font? Are you using @font-face in a CSS document?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough yes correct. `@font-face {...}`

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Can you paste the request/response you're getting from storage.googleapis.com (removing auth stuff?)  I created a web font with the exact CORS policy you created and didn't see this problem: https://yarbrough-cors-test.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: you can easily check it out here: http://www.toteme-nyc.com/shop/aw15 add an item to the cart and navigate to the checkout page. with chrome obviously

Comment: Ah! I believe you may have found a Chrome bug, see: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=544879

Comment: oh i see. thx for finding this!! if you post this as an answer ill give you the credit for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit from 2019: Chrome fixed this years ago!

Interesting! There is a Chrome bug (issue [544879](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=544879)) in which Chrome insists that it needs credentials for loading fonts, even though it does not. Looks like that's likely to be your problem.

While you wait for that bug to be fixed, you may consider these options:

1. Use HTTP instead of HTTPS when referencing storage.googleapis.com. HTTP may not be vulnerable to this problem.
2. List specific domains instead of a wildcard in yours CORS policy.
3. Rather than hosting a font and referencing it with @font-face, host a CSS file with the font encoded as a data URI. Example: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-loading.html

Answer (score 31):

Such issues, when hosting fonts on GCS, could also be related to missing CORS configuration on the GCS bucket.
(See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin).

You may define cors access settings with:

```
gsutil cors set cors-config.json gs://my-bucket
```

And your cors-config.json could be, for example:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

Meaning ok to read from all origins.

Comment: You may have to re-upload files in the bucket for them to have the CORS header present

Comment: is it possible to wildcard for subdomain like "*.stutzen.co" or "**.stutzen.co"  ?

Comment: Seems like it does not work for me after moving to new bucket... public-read set, cors set, but fonts from gs just wont load because of CORS.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the issue was that we naively used the `storage.cloud.google.com/path/to/resource` public URL as the base Url for our front-end application, while it does not allow CORS request...

Instead, we had to use the `storage.googleapis.com/path/to/resource` one!

[More information on our CORS is handled by google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#server-side-support)